# Calling external SSJS in Script Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am attempting to call an external microsite page (content type is text/javascript) in a Script activity. This external javascript contains functions to be used in multiple SSJS scripts.

edit: I also tried using a Content Area and have updated the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[micrositepage]"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript" runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var globalVarsFunctions = ContentAreaObj.Init("GlobalVarsFunctions_732226");
    ContentArea(732226);

/*
Content
*/

    // Retrieve rows and sort by priority. 
    var DE_ContentDetails_Rows = DE_ContentDetails.Rows.Retrieve();
...
</script>
```

I've removed the page in the source above, but the original contains the variable for "DE_ContentDetails".

The error I'm receiving indicates the external JS code is not being referenced as it cannot find the DE_ContentDetails object.

> Unable to generate preview A scripting error has occurred. 
> Object
>   expected: Retrieve
>  Line: 11 Char: 1 var DE_ContentDetails_Rows =
>   DE_ContentDetails.Rows.Retrieve()

Comment: I've also tried including runat="server" in the external JS call with the same issue.

Comment: whats runat="server" with javascript... runat server does not exists in Visualforce

Comment: The question is regarding SSJS for a Script Activity within the Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: is this external site inside SFMC or on a 3rd party host?

Comment: It is a micro site landing page hosted within the salesforce marketing cloud. The landing page is set up with a conent type = text/javascript.

Comment: i would move it into a content block and call the content block in the SSJS activity

Comment: I tried using the ContentArea() function to call in the SSJS code from the content area. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to include a Content Area in your SSJS code, you will first need to initialise it using the `ContentAreaObj.Init()` function as [documented here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/content_area_server_side_javascript_functions/).

You will then be able to use the `ContentArea()` or `ContentAreaByName()` SSJS functions.

Comment: Implementing this resulted in the same error. I wonder if I misinterpreted anything? I've updated the code in the original question to reflect the content area init and call.

Comment: I've tried using the documented Content Area SSJS functions and can't get them to work. It's annoying when you follow [documented code examples](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/content_area_server_side_javascript_functions/) and they don't work. Not sure what the solution would be here...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the Content Area using SSJS code then you will need to use [SSJS Utilities](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/) `Content Area` functions.

```
<script type="text/javaScript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var myContent = ContentArea(176240);
    Write(myContent);
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work and resulted in the same error. The ContentArea contains SSJS code that needs to be executed and it doesn't appear to be doing that using your suggested code.

Comment: Not sure, Maybe some problem in your contentarea sssjs code. update your content area ssjs code here